# What are the specialty of these Superman suits?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

In *Zack Snyder's Justice League* when Superman goes into his ship after his resurrection he sees 4 different suits. What is the specialty of these suits?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From left to right the suits are:

- **The Superman Suit** - The traditional skin suit and cape developed by the Jor-El AI in ambassadorial colors to bridge Krypton and Earth.
- **Female Kryptonian Armor** - Similar to that worn by Faora and the other Black Zero refugees who invaded Earth.
- **Kryptonian Space Suit** - Seen during Zod's travels to the dead colonies looking for life, the suits can be worn in no-atmosphere environments.
- **Male Kryptonian Armor** - Similar to that worn by Zod during his invasion.

[image: Female Armor]
[image: Male Armor]
[image: Zod in Space Suit]

Answer (score 10):

Also, the black costume is for energy, power and recovery in general. Thats why he flies and looks to the sun, which also gives him strength.